# How to change the background of a UIimageview to hex value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to change the background color of my UIimageview. I am aware of how to do it like this

```
 ColorBox.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

However, my program requires that the backgroundColor be set to a Hex color value.  How do i set to a Hex color instead of a UIimage text color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a link which can answer you.
Please visit http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/02/iphone-development-accessing-uicolor-components.ars

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the individual hex value for red, green and blue. This should work.

```
int red = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", redHex] intValue];
int green = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", greenHex] intValue];
int blue = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", blueHex] intValue];

[UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0 green:green/255.0 blue:blue/255.0 alpha:1]
```

Or use this to parse the string:
[How can I convert RGB hex string into UIColor in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010216/how-can-i-convert-rgb-hex-string-into-uicolor-in-objective-c)

Comment: Whenever I use this I don't get the right color coming out.  Any time I put more then 1 color over 0% it instantly turns to a pink so

10% blue and 60% red = pink
255% blue and 10%red = pink