# ios - Converting UIColor to NSData gives error when color has a pattern

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, uicolor, nskeyedarchiver

I want to convert a `UIColor` object to `NSData` so that I can save it using `NSUserDefaults`. The following code works:

```
NSData *colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[UIColor redColor]];
```

However, if I create a color using an image as follows:

```
UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mypattern.png"];
UIColor *c = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img];
NSData *colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:c];
```

I get the following error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only RGBA or White color spaces are supported in this situation.'`

Any help?

Comment: Set a color space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the need is to understand the difference between simple `UIColor` conversion  and a color extracted of `colorWithPatternImage`conversion to `NSData`.

You can only serialise certain UIColor objects.

Instead of serialising the UIColor, you need to store the image that the pattern was created from. Do this in your encodeWithCoder:

Then, in your initWithCoder: you should dearchive the image and create a new UIColor from that
Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456835/saving-uicolor-colorwithpatternimageimage-uicolor-to-core-data-using-nskeyeda) (preferred) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470018/uicolor-crash-when-attempt-to-archive-uicolor-object) .

> When you create your `UIColor color = [UIColor
>   colorWithPatternImage:selectedImage]`, also set the associated object
>   on the color `[color setAssociatedObject:selectedImage]`.

Comment: "Instead of serialising the UIColor, you need to store the image that the pattern was created from."  Que!?