# iOS - Archiving a UILabel with image as background

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data, serialization, uilabel

I am using colorWithPatternImage to set the background image of a UILabel but, when I come to archive it, I get the following error:

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only support RGBA or the White color space, this method is a hack.'
```

Which is the case, I guess it is a hack. My question is: is it possible to archive an image as part of a labels background? 
I have subclassed UILabel for a different reason, is there anything I can add in order to set an image as a background with the existing subclass?

For clarity, this is the code that causes the problem:

```
NSData *viewData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:label];
```

Where label is a UILabel that has a background image set, using colorWithPatternImage.

Cheers!

Comment: Please show some code that gives you this error

Comment: Simple code like: NSData *viewData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:label]; if the background of the UILabel has been set with the previously mentioned colorWithPatternImage.

Comment: can you please update the original question and add the code in its entirity with the code blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you had the same problem as

[Saving [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image] UIColor to Core Data using NSKeyedArchiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456835/saving-uicolor-colorwithpatternimageimage-uicolor-to-core-data-using-nskeyeda/7477462#7477462)

Comment: I looked at that, seemed like an excessive solution. Wondered if there was a better way by subclassing? I.e. embedding an image view?

Comment: I couldnt find a better way. Maybe you can use a DTS ticket with Apple to find a simpler and more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is in your UILabel subclass, you create an ivar to store the pattern image and you archived the ivar. When you unarchive your UILabel subclass, you recreate the pattern image with the image ivar.

Sample code for the label.

```
@implementation ESKLabelArchive

@synthesize backgroundImage=_backgroundImage;

#pragma mark - NSCoding Protocols
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        self.backgroundImage = (UIImage *)[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"backgroundImage"];
        if (self.backgroundImage != nil)
            self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:self.backgroundImage];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage
{
    _backgroundImage = [backgroundImage copy];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:_backgroundImage];
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    if (self.backgroundImage != nil)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [aCoder encodeObject:self.backgroundImage forKey:@"backgroundImage"];
    }
    [super encodeWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self.backgroundImage != nil)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:self.backgroundImage];
    }
}



@end
```

Sampel View Controller

```
@implementation ESKViewController

@synthesize label;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (IBAction)archivedTapped:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:self.label forKey:@"label"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];

    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    ESKLabelArchive *label2 = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"label"];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];

    label2.text = @"unarchived";
    label2.frame = CGRectMake(20, 150, 200, 100);

    [self.view addSubview:label2];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.label.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ricepaper.png"];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.label = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Comment: I have looked into doing it this way, as it seems best but I get a BAD_ACCESS when trying to encode the image. I assume it does not conform to NSCoding?