# how to copy one view to another view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, copy

I want to copy one UIView to another view without making it archive or unarchive.
Please help me if you have any solution.

I tried with by making an extension of UIView as already available an answer on Stack over flow. But its crashing when I pass the view with pattern Image Background color.

Comment: Can you add the link of the answer you already tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121655/create-a-copy-of-a-uiview-in-swift

Comment: extension UIView
    {
        func copyView() -> AnyObject
        {
            return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self))!
        }
    }

Comment: I think you are forgetting to cast the object returned from `copyView` into a `UIView`. If that is the case you can make `copyView` to return a `UIView?` so there is no need for casting later

Answer (score 3):

The code related to my comment below:

```
extension UIView
{
    func copyView() -> UIView?
    {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self)) as? UIView
    }
}
```

I've just tried this simple code in a Playground to check that the copy view works and it's not pointing the same view:

```
let originalView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50));
originalView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
let originalLabel = UILabel(frame: originalView.frame);
originalLabel.text = "Hi";
originalLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
originalView.addSubview(originalLabel);

let copyView = originalView.copyView();
let copyLabel = copyView?.subviews[0] as! UILabel;

originalView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();
originalLabel.text = "Hola";

originalView.backgroundColor;   // Returns black
originalLabel.text;             // Returns "Hola"
copyView!.backgroundColor;      // Returns red
copyLabel.text;                 // Returns "Hi"
```

If the extension wouldn't work, both `copyView` and `originalView` would have same `backgroundColor` and the same would happen to the text of the labels. So maybe there is the possibility that the problem is in other part.

Comment: I've just double checked it in a Playground and the copy is working fine. So I've just updated my answer with the code I used in case you can find it helpful

Comment: Don't take fix color....use some image for background color. Then its not working.

Comment: Oh right, sorry. Then your problem is not copying a UIView is encoding an UIColor when it's created from a pattern.
You can find a solution to that problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7477462/1387646)

Answer (score -1):

### Original Post

```
   func copyView(viewforCopy: UIView) -> UIView {
        viewforCopy.hidden = false //The copy not works if is hidden, just prevention
        let viewCopy = viewforCopy.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
        viewforCopy.hidden = true
        return viewCopy
    }
```

---

### Updated for Swift 4

```
func copyView(viewforCopy: UIView) -> UIView {
    viewforCopy.isHidden = false //The copy not works if is hidden, just prevention
    let viewCopy = viewforCopy.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
    viewforCopy.isHidden = true
    return viewCopy!
}
```

Comment: This does not copy the view with its live hierarchy. It produces a static picture of the view at the time `snapshotView...` was called.