# How to create CGColor with HTML representation string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I need to create a CGColor form the HTML representation string like [NSColor colorWithHTMLName:]
But only by means of CoreGraphics

Comment: GIMME TEH CODEZ-style questions are not considered to be good. What have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010216/how-can-i-convert-rgb-hex-string-into-uicolor-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CGColorRef CGColorFromHTMLString(NSString *str)
{
    // remove the leading "#" and add a "0x" prefix
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%@", [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, str.length - 1)]];

    NSScanner *scanner;
    uint32_t result;

    scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
    [scanner scanHexInt:&result];

    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(((result >> 16) & 0xff) / 255.0, ((result >> 8) & 0xff) / 255.0, ((result >> 0) & 0xff) / 255.0, 1.0);

    return color;
}
```

Don't forget to free the result after use by calling `CGColorRelease` on it.

EDIT: if you don't want to use Foundation, try CFStringRef or a plain C string:

```
CGColorRef CGColorFromHTMLString(const char *str)
{

    uint32_t result;
    sscanf(str + 1, "%x", &result);

    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(((result >> 16) & 0xff) / 255.0, ((result >> 8) & 0xff) / 255.0, ((result >> 0) & 0xff) / 255.0, 1.0);

    return color;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man ! +1 from me, posting pure CoreGraphics solution as an another answer

Comment: No problem. (I'm just familiar with the docs -- where to look for this and that.)

Comment: Wait -- you don't have to use Foundation classes. CFStringRef is toll-free bridged with NSString. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to H2CO3 !

Here is the CoreGraphics solution i.e. no Foundation classes but Coregraphics and C++

```
    // Remove the preceding "#" symbol
    if (backGroundColor.find("#") != string::npos) {
        backGroundColor = backGroundColor.substr(1);
    }
    unsigned int decimalValue;
    sscanf(backGroundColor.c_str(), "%x", &decimalValue); 
    printf("\nstring=%s, decimalValue=%u",backGroundColor.c_str(), decimalValue);

    CGColorRef result = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(((decimalValue >> 16) & 0xff) / 255.0, ((decimalValue >> 8) & 0xff) / 255.0, ((decimalValue >> 0) & 0xff) / 255.0, 1.0);
```